# Using JQuery / JS & Select Boxes to change the stylesheet depending on the selection

Tags: jquery, css

Using JQuery / JS & Select Boxes to change the stylesheet depending on the selection I want the user to be able to, say, select "Super Admin" from a drop down select box and have the div that contains the description of user level "Super admin" (located below the form) to change its

`.superAdmin div {background-color: #000;}`

I assume its some form of manipulation of the `onChange();` handle.

Sorry if this questions is ridiculously low level, but I am a real beginner with JS, let along JQuery. +1 if you can also supply exactly how to implement the code (what to put in the `<head></head>` tags)

Thanks in advance, Huge supporter of this site (90% of all the issues I run into have already been asked here, I just couldnt find anything on this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a CSS stylesheet with the definition of all the classes you may want to add:

```
.user {background-color: #F00;}
.admin {background-color: #0F0;}
.superAdmin {background-color: #00F;}
```

and you have the HTML for your select box:

```
<select id="css-changer">
    <option></option>
    <option value="user">User</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="superAdmin">Super Admin</option>
</select>
```

and for your divs:

```
<div id="user">User div</div>
<div id="admin">Admin div</div>
<div id="superAdmin">Super Admin div</div>
```

Then your javascript with jQuery would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#css-changer").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        switch(value) {
            case "user":
                $("#user").addClass("user");
                $("#admin,#superAdmin").removeClass(); // removes all classes
                break;
            case "admin":
                $("#admin").addClass("admin");
                $("#user,#superAdmin").removeClass(); // removes all classes
                break;
            case "superAdmin":
                $("#superAdmin").addClass("superAdmin");
                $("#user,#admin").removeClass(); // removes all classes
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

You can [see this working](http://jsfiddle.net/JtzAL/1/).

To get the JS and CSS in your page, create an external style sheet with the right definitions and include it [as described by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.3.2) with a tag like that below:

```
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and make sure to include jQuery and an external javascript file (to make things unobtrusive).  To include them use HTML like that below:

```
<!-- jQuery goes first! -->
<script src="path/to/jQuery/CDN/jquery-min-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
$("#div").change(function(){

    $("#div1").css("color", "red");

})
```